# Time span between Acts 18:2 till Acts 21:17

Tags: acts, paul, chronology

Is it possible to know how much time passed between Acts 18:2 and Acts 21:17, that is, till Paul's last visit to Jerusalem?

> After these things Paul departed from Athens, and came to Corinth
> (Acts 18:1, KJV)
>
> And when we were come to Jerusalem, the brethren received us gladly.
> (Acts 21:17, KJV)

According to my estimates, it must be a little more than three years, but I am not sure. I don't know which factors to take into account in order to count the time in Acts precisely enough.

Comment: I slightly reworded the first sentence and added the chronology tag; if you don't like my edits I'm happy to roll them back. I threw a few sources into my post if you're interested in further reading on the Pauline chronology.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

---

Approximately 7 years

---

An honest historian must acknowledge that with the Pauline chronology the best we can do is usually +/- a year or so, but we can date several events in his ministry closely enough to create an internally consistent timeline.

**Arrival in Corinth**

This is approximately AD 50. Two of the most helpful markers here are:

- Claudius' expulsion of the Jews from Rome - Paulus Orosius dates this event to the 9th year of Claudius—presumably AD 49 (Historiae adversum paganos 7.6.15-16), although some have questioned his precision. If the expulsion occurred in AD 49 (or even just relatively close to it), that would put Paul in Corinth in the early 50s.
- Paul's trial before Gallio, the deputy of Achaia (Acts 18:12-16) - thanks to an inscription we know with fairly decent precision when Gallio was in office and can date this event in Paul’s life to approximately AD 51 (maybe 52). See a detailed discussion on the inscription and its significance [here](http://richardwaynegarganta.com/redating-testament.pdf) (pp. 33-34)

Since Acts 18:2 suggests that Claudius' expulsion edict (~49) is a recent event, and the Gallio trial in 51 or 52 takes place after Paul has been in Corinth for 18 months (Acts 18:11), Paul arrived in Corinth in about AD 50.

**Final (recorded) trip to Jerusalem**

This is approximately AD 57; we can arrive at this date two ways:

- Counting back from the beginning of the tenure of Porcius Festus.
  Paul has been in custody for 2 years by this time (Acts 24:27), and a
  decent estimate for the beginning of Festus' term is AD 59, meaning
  Paul's arrest and imprisonment under Felix--which came shortly after
  his arrival as noted in the OP, would be AD 57. A more detailed
  discussion of the Festus chronology by Robinson is found [here](http://richardwaynegarganta.com/redating-testament.pdf)
  (pp. 40-43).
- Counting forward from Paul's time in Corinth. The longest timespans noted in Acts are the 18+ month interval in Corinth (Acts 18:11), and the 2+ years in Ephesus (Acts 19:10), though many exegetes hold that Paul was in Ephesus for longer than two years. Incorporating the numerous other travels, observances of feasts, etc., Paul's 2nd and 3rd missionary journeys require 7 or 8 years.

**A plausible timeline**

- AD 49 - Paul embarks on 2nd missionary journey
- AD 50 - Paul arrives in Corinth (OP passage #1), where he will be for more than 18 months
- AD 52 or 53 - Paul returns to Judea (see Acts 18:20), after additional time in Corinth + a trip to Ephesus
- AD 53 - Paul embarks on his 3rd missionary journey, which includes a 2+ year stay in Ephesus
- AD 56 - Paul travels to Corinth, winters there, and writes his Epistle to the Romans
- AD 57 - Paul returns to Jerusalem in the Spring (OP passage #2)

**Conclusion**

If Paul arrived in Corinth circa AD 50 and arrived in Jerusalem circa AD 57, there's a 7-year interval between the references noted in the OP.

Note that Paul did in fact make 1 trip to (or near) Jerusalem in between these events, to attend the feast noted in Acts 18:20-21.